# Elastic Beanstalk Wrong Ruby version even though specified in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm launching a ruby on rails application on AWS EB and am getting the following error

> [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] -
> [stage ruby application]. Stop running the command. Error: install
> dependencies in Gemfile failed with error Command /bin/sh -c bundle
> *2.4.1* install failed with error exit status 18. Stderr:Don't run Bundler as root. Installing your bundle as root will break this
> application for all non-root users on this machine. Your Ruby version
> is 3.0.5, but your Gemfile specified 3.0.0

I've triple checked the Gemfile in the directory I'm running EB commands from and am positive it has ruby "3.0.5" specified:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.0.5"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Use Tailwind CSS [https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails]
gem "tailwindcss-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end

gem 'pg'

gem 'devise'

gem "rqrcode"
```

using the commands

```
$ eb init

$ eb create
```

What could be causing the error saying my Gemfile specified 3.0.0?

Comment: Had you previously deployed with version 3.0?

Comment: @littleforest yes, is there a way to undo that?

Comment: You might want to try the immutable deployments in the short term to force brand-new servers to get deployed. I'm wondering if there is something else that needs to get fixed and so your new Gemfile is never deployed, but the error message ends up being about the Gemfile which is not useful. "When you configure Elastic Beanstalk to use immutable updates for application deployments, it replaces all instances in your environment every time you deploy a new version of your application" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentmgmt-updates-immutable.html